# Error while trying to compile android kernel in ubuntu

Tags: android, linux-kernel, arm64

I'm trying to compile a Android Kernel from source and I have downloaded all the right packages to do it but for some reason I get this error:

```
arm-linux-androideabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '-mgeneral-regs-only'
/home/livlogik/android/kernel/H901BK_L_Kernel/./Kbuild:35: recipe for target 'kernel/bounds.s' failed
make[1]: *** [kernel/bounds.s] Error 1
Makefile:858: recipe for target 'prepare0' failed
make: *** [prepare0] Error 2
```

I have the latest NDK and I'm using Ubuntu 15.10 64bit if this helps.

Here is where I have the NDK and kernel:

**NDK** ---- /home/livlogik/android/ndk/

**Kernel** ---- /home/livlogik/android/kernel/H901bk_L_Kernel/

If someone could help me that would be great. Sorry if this was already posted I could find a answer to it.

Thanks,

Zach

Comment: Seems like wrong toolchain. Try [this](https://releases.linaro.org/14.04/components/toolchain/binaries/gcc-linaro-arm-none-eabi-4.8-2014.04_linux.tar.bz2) one. Be sure to setup `PATH`, `CROSS_COMPILE` and `ARCH` environment variables properly before building, as usual.

Comment: @SamProtsenko will this toolchain work for a Android kernel. In inside files look diffrent that the tool chain in the NDK. Also when you say setup PATH, CROSS_COMPILE and ARCH do you mean in the .bashrc file? Sorry bare with me lol this is my first time messing with Android kernels. Thanks for helping btw

Comment: Yes, this is ARM bare-metal gcc toolchain, I'm pretty sure it'll work for kernel. As for variables -- you can just set them in your shell via `export` command, like `export PATH=......:$PATH`, etc. Then run `make` in this shell, and those variables will be used by kernel Makefile.

Comment: See [this](https://wiki.linaro.org/Boards/DRA7EVM#Download_toolchains) for downloading toolchain and [this](https://wiki.linaro.org/Boards/DRA7EVM#Configuring_toolchain) for configuring toolchain. To build kernel I guess you need to run `make defconfig` first (or even use `merge_config.sh` script before to apply Android changes), then run `make` to build kernel. In the end I guess you need to build device tree for your board.

Comment: Your NDK toolchain should work fine too, probably you haven't configured it properly (those variables I mentioned). Pay your attention especially to `PATH`, it should contain path to toolchain's `bin/` directory, followed by previous `PATH` value. Also make sure you chose correct toolchain from NDK (if there are several toolchains there).

Comment: @SamProtsenko ok thanks I'll look into all that. How do I know which tool chain is the right one? Also to do the export do I have to be in the kernel main directory? And will I have to do it every time I compile? Sorry for all the questions

Comment: Usually you need ARM EABI toolchain (so the prefix is `arm-none-eabi-`) to build kernel, because kernel is bare-metal program by its nature. You can export variables in any directory, just be sure that you are using the same shell for building kernel. So directory doesn't matter, but the shell instance (terminal) does. You need to export those variables one time per shell, so when opening new shell you need to prepare build environment first (export variables). Another way to do that is to save them to `.bashrc`.

Comment: @SamProtsenko oh ok so say I want to use the ndk I have. I should open up the terminal I'm going to compile in and type --->

Comment: I don't really know what your NDK contains of, but first you need to find which toolchains it has. Look for `arm-none-eabi-` toolchain or something similar. Next you need to export variables (see links I mentioned above).

Comment: @SamProtsenko sorry I didn't finish my reply. So in the terminal I am going to use to compile I could try ----  'export PATH=$PATH:~/android/ndk/android-ndk-r7-linux-x86/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/linux-x86/bin and and then export ARCH and then export CROSS_COMPILE'? Then I should be good to go if my tool chain is right

Comment: Basically yes, but I think `arm-linux-androidea‌​bi` is actually Linux toolchain, intended for Linux user-space programs. Is there something else in `toolchains/` directory?

Comment: @SamProtsenko Yeah the folders are -->  

**/home/livlogik/android/ndk/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3** and

**/home/livlogik/android/ndk/android-ndk-r7/toolchains/x86-4.4.3**

Comment: Ok, so the only choice here is `arm-linux-androideabi-`. Well, try it as I described above, and if the problem still persists, try Linaro `arm-none-eabi-` toolchain I mentioned earlier.

Comment: @SamProtsenko thanks. i just tried it and i am still getting errors im following the instructions for linaro hopefully i do everything right lol

Comment: If it won't help -- then provide next information: the link and branch of kernel you are trying to build (so I can obtain it); the link to NDK you are using; board name for which you want to build the kernel (and probably corresponding defconfig name). And I'll write complete instructions how to build it as a full answer (not sure though if NDK toolchain will cut it).

Comment: @SamProtsenko wow ok thank you I'm doing it now so fingers crossed haha if it doesn't work I'll send you the informations

Comment: @SamProtsenko well i found out that im supposed to be building under aarch64 i belive. I still get a error though. it starts to compile fine but then it gets to a certain part and i get this --->

`CC      drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/sensor/msm_sensor.o
drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/sensor/msm_sensor.c:20:27: fatal error: ./mh1/msm_mh1.h: No such file or directory
 #include <./mh1/msm_mh1.h>
                           ^
compilation terminated.`

i tried the android ndk and linaro still the same thing. i thought it would work because it started to compile for like 10 min.

Comment: @SamProtsenko  here is the info you wanted --- Not sure about the branch. No one has made a custom kernel for this phone yet (its the T-Mobile LG v10).  **NDK Link** ---> [http://developer.android.com/ndk/downloads/index.html]  **Kernel Source** ---> [http://opensource.lge.com/osSch/list?types=ALL&search=h901bk]  **Board Name** = msm8992  **Defconfig Name** = pplus_tmo_us-perf_defconfig (in the kernel source read me it says to use this defconfig)(its in /arch/arm64/configs)

Comment: Ok, I will look into it a bit later. But for aarch64 you should use aarch64 toolchain, arm toolchain won't cut it.

Comment: @SamProtsenko ok thanks. Yeah once I found out it was aarach64 I switched to the linaro aarch64 tool chain and then when I got that error 2 comments up I switched to the Android ndk which is the link I sent it's the android-ndk-r10e-linux-x86_64 and used the aarch64-linux-android-4.9... But still got the same error for the man_sensor.c

Comment: @SamProtsenko hey just wanted to let you know I got it working thanks for all the help. They only problem I'm having now is that when I flash it ..it doesn't read my external sd card it says sd card empty or not supported. But when I take my sd card out and put it into my computer all my files are there..  And that I can set SELinux to permissive. ... But anyways thanks for all the help!

Comment: Really glad to hear it, man! You can publish your findings as an additional answer to this question, so that folks can learn from it. Or create external documentation (like wiki page with instructions). I'm also curious, because it's real arm64 machine and I think it's future for mobile devices, so as engineer I should start looking into it. As for SELinux -- I guess default mode is `enforced` now, so you should create new rule for SD card. Look [here](https://source.android.com/security/selinux/validate.html#using_audit2allow) for details on how to do that ("Using audit2allow" section).

Comment: @SamProtsenko thanks Yeah I will post it once I get my first kernel released and learn a little more about it. And thanks I fixed the SELinux last night sorry I should have posted that I fixed it so you didn't look for a answer.  answer. I agree it seems different that doing a kernel for arm. That's for all the help. I'll let you know if I find out how to fix the sd card problem :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it can be seen from build error message:

> **drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/sensor/msm_sensor.c**:20:27: fatal error: ./mh1/msm_mh1.h: No such file or directory
>
> **#include <./mh1/msm_mh1.h>**

compiler just can't find `msm_mh1.h` file. This is because the path specified for `#include` directive isn't correct. Most probably it's typo: instead `./` there should be `../`.

To fix that error, in `drivers/media/platform/msm/camera_v2/sensor/msm_sensor.c` file change this line:

```c
#include <./mh1/msm_mh1.h>
```

to this line

```c
#include "../mh1/msm_mh1.h"
```

After this `make` command should work fine. Also, kernel image file will be available at `arch/arm64/boot`, and it's not `zImage` as stated in documentation, it's actually `Image.gz`. Uncompressed kernel image is `Image` file.

### Update

Answering your question in comments:

> *Is there any way to make it compress into a zImage?*

From [Documentation/arm64/booting.txt](https://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/arm64/booting.txt):

> The AArch64 kernel does not currently provide a decompressor and
>   therefore requires decompression (gzip etc.) to be performed by the boot
>   loader if a compressed `Image` target (e.g. `Image.gz`) is used.  For
>   bootloaders that do not implement this requirement, the uncompressed
>   `Image` target is available instead.

Basically `zImage` is just gzipped and self-extracted `Image`. So `zImage` file consists of program for unpacking gzip archive in the beginning, followed by gzipped `Image`, and when kernel is run by bootloader its unpacking itself (hense "self-extracted" term) and then start running.

> *...So I can make it flashable*

In case of arm64, you don't have `zImage`, so most likely you need to use `Image` file (which acts in the same way, but only its size is bigger). You can create `boot.img` from `Image` file and built AFS ramdisk (using `mkbootimg` tool) and then just do `fastboot flash boot boot.img`. Refer to [this](https://github.com/96boards/documentation/wiki/Dragonboard-410c-Boot-Image) documentation for example. Of course for your platform some things can be different, so try to find instructions for your platform.

Comment: You are awesome! I will try this later tonight and cross my fingers! Thank you sir I would have not ever guessed that

Comment: sweet thank you it compiled and I didn't see any errors! Is there any way to make it compress into a zImage? So I can make it flashable

Comment: See **Update** in the answer.

Comment: Ok so there is no way to make it flashable in recovery like cwm or twrp? They will have to flash it through fastboot?

Comment: I don't know about CWM/TWRP (never really heard of it), but if it allows you to flash boot partition, you can use obtained `boot.img` file (I described how to create it) and flash it to boot partition. Because `boot.img` is just an image of boot partition. Is it sufficient? If no, please describe the format of image that CWM/TWRP use and perhaps I can help you to come up with some way to create it from kernel's `Image` file.

Comment: Ok well I will mess around with it. Thanks so much for your help!! Do you have email or anything where I can contact you sometime and pick your brain lol

Comment: If you have any further questions you can ask here or (if it's not related) you can ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

You have to install the right toolchain:

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/aarch64/aarch64-linux-android-4.9`

And configure the Makefile appropriately

The *wrong* toolchain is at

`git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/prebuilts/gcc/linux-x86/arm/arm-linux-android-4.9`