# /arm64/Image to zImage or boot.img

Tags: android, linux, linux-kernel, kernel

Hello everyone I have been trying to figure out how to make my android kernel a zImage or boot.img.

I tried to figure it out with no luck. I was told that zImage isnt possible for my device because its a arm64 kernel but I thought I would ask again.

if that’s the case I'm trying to get the boot.img compiled so I can fastboot it.

This is for the LG v10.

Thanks,

Zach

Comment: Just for the reference: this question is connected to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35631171/error-while-trying-to-compile-android-kernel-in-ubuntu/35656183?noredirect=1#comment59050834_35656183) question.

Comment: Have you tried to create `boot.img` from `Image` file using `mkbootimg` tool?

Comment: @SamProtsenko thanks I should have added that. I tried the link you gave me but I couldn't get it to work and I tried to do a boot.img and couldn't get it to work either.  Lol this has been difficult :p

Comment: @SamProtsenko yeah i don't know what I'm doing wrong with the mkbooting tool but it keeps not working

Comment: What do you man "not working"? It's not able to produce `boot.img`, or produced `boot.img` won't boot?

Comment: @SamProtsenko it's probably a user error haha I'm going to try again tonight and see if I can't get it.

Comment: @SamProtsenko I can't figure out were to put the mkbooting tool files and when I think I figured out and do the command it work do it I'm going to try again tonight and see if I'm missing something or just completely doing it wrong haha

Comment: Ok. As I see it, first of all you need to figure out where your kernel *should* be flashed for your device. Can you observe partitions table in some way? You should look if you have partition called `boot` on your device. And (desirable) look what is the size of that partition. If it's in place, then create `boot.img` from `Image` file and `ramdisk.img` (from Android your AFS build) using `mkbootimg` tool (there may be some subtle pitfalls, though). Once `boot.img` is created, see if it fits into `boot` partition. If it is, flash it using `fastboot flash boot boot.img` or in any other way.

Comment: Ok i just watched a video of how to view and get the boot.img from the device using adb. But if I make the Image a boot.img and flash with fastboot it would it replace the rest of the boot.img on the device because I just want to flash the kernel. Or would it just put the kernel files into the existing boot.img on my device?

Comment: You can try to use `make bootimage` target for Android sources. See [this](https://source.android.com/source/building-kernels.html#building). It will use `mkbootimg` automatically for known (built) ramdisk and the kernel image you specify.

Comment: `boot.img` consists of kernel image **and** ramdisk. So flashing `boot.img` will replace both kernel and ramdisk. You need to be sure that `boot.img` was generated correctly (correct kernel image, ramdisk and other options). Otherwise you risk to brick your device. I'd recommend you to use `make bootimage` rule in Android sources tree (after building both AFS and kernel).

Comment: Also I guess `boot.img` **may** contain device tree (from kernel build). I'm not sure if you need one in your case, and where it should be put (into `boot.img` or into separate partition). Unfortunately, you don't have clear instructions for your device, so it's always a risk. I advice you to prepare some way to restore things, before you start flashing (very likely you will brick your device on first attempt). And I advice you to figure out the partition table for your device first, to get a clue about DT (device tree) destination.

Comment: Sounds good. Thanks for all the help i jumped into some deep waters haha. I have my whole system backed up so I can just go into recovery and restore everything if it bricks. In sort of confused about the ramdisk and AFS could I just copy those from the boot.img I pull from my device and just through in the Image file?

Comment: Yes, you can unpack your `boot.img`. Just google for `unpack boot.img ubuntu` or something like that, there are a lot of working answers out there.

Comment: Ok sound good I'll see what I can do from there. Yeah it just seems when I try to find working answers I can never find any lol

Comment: The thing is what you really need is working instructions (how to build and flash kernel + Android) for your board. But there isn't. So you have a lot of questions, one triggers another. So you either should ask for instructions on LG open source (or XDA developers forum), or ask someone who have LG v10 to come up with instructions and share it. Or you can figure out those instructions by yourself. All options seem quite painful, but we can't help you because we just don't have LG v10 :)

Comment: Yeah I understand lol. Most devs gave up not the v10 but I'm going to keep pluging away. I figure I'll find out how sooner or later :p. Thanks for the help I'll keep you posted how it goes

Answer (score 4):

There is no way to do that other than to hack the naming convention inside your kernel.

64 bit arm kernels will be compiled under name of **"Image"**

32 bit arm kernels will be compiled under name of **"zImage"**

Comment: Thanks for the response! So if I change the 64 bit in the naming convention inside my kernel to zImage it should compile as a zImage? Also where would I find the naming convention in my kernel?

Comment: @SundeepBorra It's more than just convention. `zImage` is self-extracted archive, and `Image` is just plain not packed kernel image. arm64 kernel doesn't have decompressing capacity, hence result file is `Image`. See linked question for details.

Comment: Thanks to Sam
@Zach, you need to hack through this(Zipping thing) too, as per Sam.
But, doing so many hacks doesn't seem worth the change unless the requirement is so tempting and mandatory. More explanation of your use case would attract better answers. 
Why not the Image work for you?